# how to bind the objectdatasource to html select <tag>?

Tags: html, asp.net

**Is there any way to bind a objectdatasource to an html select tag with runat=server attribute.**

```
<select size="1" id='standard' onchange="toggleOption(this)" name='standard' class='custom-select' >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

as like as an asp dropdown list box

```
<select size="1" id="standard" runat="server" onchange="toggleOption(this)" name='standard' class='custom-select' >
```

C# Code

```
 standard.DataTextField = "title";
        standard.DataValueField = "val";
        standard.DataSource = SrCity;
        standard.DataBind();
```

Comment: i had tried the above code,how can i use html Id(standard) in c# code.it is  showing error cannot resolve the symbol 'standard'